# Combine the reports from two activity modules in Moodle

Tags: php, mysql, totara

I have two different `activity` `modules`, the first is a standard `Moodle` module and the second is developed by me. 
In each of them we have

```
mod/moodlemodule/rb_sources/rb_source_moodlemodule_presence.php
mod/newmodule/rb_sources/rb_source_newmodule_presence.php
```

Each one of them has the following standard functions(the code is shortened):

```
     protected function define_columnoptions() {
            global $DB;
            $usernamefieldscreator = totara_get_all_user_name_fields_join('creator');
            $usernamefieldsbooked  = totara_get_all_user_name_fields_join('bookedby');
            $columnoptions = array(
                new rb_column_option(

    protected function define_filteroptions() {
            $filteroptions = array(
                new rb_filter_option(

    public function rb_filter_position_types_list() {
            global $CFG, $POSITION_TYPES;

            include_once($CFG->dirroot.'/totara/hierarchy/prefix/position/lib.php');

            return $POSITION_TYPES;
        }

        protected function define_contentoptions() {
            $contentoptions = array(
                new rb_content_option(

protected function define_paramoptions() {
        $paramoptions = array(
            new rb_param_option(

protected function define_defaultcolumns() {
        $defaultcolumns = array(
            array(

    protected function define_requiredcolumns() {
        $requiredcolumns = array();

        $requiredcolumns[] = new rb_column(

protected function define_defaultfilters() {
        $defaultfilters = array(
            array(
```

They can be found in every report file of the activity modules and they deliver  the same data (as they are standards in almost every other module):

> `name`  `email`  `startdate`  `finishdate` `address` `coursename`

Is it possible to add the data from the both reports in one single report and display it? And how to structure the code inside the new rb_source file?

Comment: Hi Freud. The report builder reports are in Totara not Moodle. Is your company a subscriber or a partner?

Comment: We are partner, but everything is still in the beginning and because of the similarities to Moodle, where I have a bit of experience, I am still figuring out how to handle the problem.

Comment: Ah okay, can you add me or send me a message via LinkedIn and I'll point you in the right direction for Totara related questions - http://www.linkedin.com/in/russellengland